# Zip or Merge two IObservable sequences where one sequence can fail

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have a requirement that sees the merging of two IObservable sequences but with the potential for one of these sequences to fail without impacting the observer.

So taking the example from the Intro to Rx book of a sequence of numbers and characters that are zipped together:

```
nums  --0--1--2|

chars --a--b--c--d--e--f|

result -0--1--2|

        a  b  c|
Prints:
0 & a
1 & b
2 & c
```

How would you go about doing this but allowing for one of these sequences to fail (throw an exception) but without halting the execution of the subscribed observers?

```
nums  --0--1--2--3|

chars --a--b--X--d--e--f|

result -0--1--2--3|

        a  b  X  d|
Prints:
0 & a
1 & b
2 & NO VALUE
3 & d
```

I'm a bit bamboozled with Catch, Finally, OnErrorResumeNext etc and how I could apply this to my use case. All help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bear in mind the Rx grammar. A sequence is defined as follows:

```
OnNext* (OnError | OnCompleted)
```

In other words, a sequence has zero or more OnNext events, followed by an OnError or an OnCompleted. (This ignores the temporal aspect in that it could be an infinitely long stream, so a stream that never completed is still valid).

The key point is that a stream can have at most one error. Once it's sent `OnError`, no more events can be sent.

Now, it's possible to wrap a badly behaving source stream with something like OnErrorResumeNext - but you have to have a new stream for your wrapper to resume with... the first stream is dead.

Typically, in this situation you will have some kind of underlying hot source of events you want to be able to resume "live" (i.e., you don't want to start over from the first event).

#### Example Setup

I will simulate this scenario. Unfortunately, there's going to be a fair amount of setup - but in reality creating these recoverable streams generally takes a bit of work anyway!

I'll first create a factory function that gets a subscription to a contrived hot source of letters emitted once per second. This will be called to "recover" the subscription to the underlying data.

First we can create an error free letter stream by zipping a timer with an array of letters:

```
var letters = new [] { "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f" };
var letterStream = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1))
                             .Zip(letters, (_, ls) => ls);
```

Now, we will `Publish` this to make it hot - subscriptions to the published stream will pick it up from wherever it's got to:

```
var hotLetterStream = letterStream.Publish();
```

Now we can create an observable that will, on subscription, subscribe to the live stream and fail if it sees letter "c". This is a little tricky, but don't worry too much here - it's not the main point of the example, we just need a stream that gives us the underlying hot data and fails on a particular value. It exhibits the property of observable streams in that they can only error once.

```
var failStream = hotLetterStream.SelectMany(x =>  x == "c"
        ? Observable.Throw<string>(new Exception()) 
        : Observable.Return(x));
```

Now we can set up the number stream - it just returns a zero-based value a second for 4 seconds:

```
var numberStream = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1)).Take(4);
```

Now we can combine the streams with `Zip` - we use `Catch` to replace the failed letter with the "NO VALUE" single valued stream, and then `Repeat` to seamlessly concatenate a brand new subscription to the hot source:

```
var combinedStream = numberStream.Zip(
    failStream.Catch<string, Exception>(ex => Observable.Return("NO VALUE"))
              .Repeat(), (ns,ls) => ns + " & " + ls);
```

Now we can subscribe to this:

```
combinedStream.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

And finally we must "switch on" the published stream with `Connect` to start values flowing:

```
hotLetterStream.Connect();
```

This code runs as written if you pull in nuget package rx-main and produces the following output:

```
0 & a
1 & b
2 & NO VALUE
3 & d
```

#### Communicating Errors

Now in this trivial example, we communicated the error by replacing the letter with the "NO VALUE" string. That's fine for this example, and may work for you. In reality however, dealing with a failed stream like this can result in messy checks all over your code.

Fortunately, there is a clean solution. You want to use the idea of an Error monad. This is natively supported in languages like Haskell, but the idea can be easily adopted in Rx. It works by providing a special container - much like `Nullable<T>` works in .NET - but instead of holding a value or null, it holds a value or an exception.

It can be thought of as a specialization of the more general `Either<TLeft, TRight>` monad - which has a left and right side. This is implemented by Dave Sexton in his wonderful [Rxx extension to Rx](http://rxx.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Either&referringTitle=Documentation). The link is straight to a discussion of `Either`. It's easy enough to create your own version too.

So instead of subscribing to `IObservable<T>` you wrap your T in an `IObservable<Either<TException, T>>`. If the value is good, send it on with `Either.Right` - if it's bad use `Either.Left` to forward the exception (this is the general convention - e.g. good "right" bad "left"). You can even create a an `Error` type to wrap `Either` and restrict `TLeft` to an exception. Operators that care about the value can check the left and right properties, operators that don't just pass on the value oblivious to whether it's an error or not - just as .NET functions can work with `Nullable<T>` without necessarily caring whether the value is a null or not.

In this way, you can propagate an exception down lengthy observable chains to an ultimate subscriber in a clean and understandable fashion.

Another takeaway here is that it's often important to distinguish between errors in the data that you may want to communicate, from errors in the stream plumbing that take down the system. Don't jump to  using `OnError` to communicate a bad piece of data - because this kills the stream. Instead, consider just sending an error value down the stream.

A gist with the full code for this sample is here: https://gist.github.com/james-world/904ca7383a8f1cd349b9

Comment: Many thanks for that, not able to digest it at the moment but will get time look at it later. I'm confident from skim reading though that it appears to address my scenario.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think your post finnaly helps me to grasp error handling in RX. Brilliant!